# How can i fixed "Build Error in installShield 2020"

Tags: installshield

Error -9039: ISSQLScriptFile Table
The conversion process does not support data in the MSI table 'ISSQLScriptFile'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use SQL scripts much in MSI installers, and I don't have access to Installshield, but please read this: https://docs.revenera.com/installshield26helplib/helplibrary/Citrix9039.htm

Unsure of the context for the error - are you converting an MSI to an ISM? (the latter is an Installshield project file as opposed to a normal MSI installer file - the ISM file is - or at least used to be - an MSI-formatted file in disguise with Installshield-specific tables added).

If you are converting to ISM, maybe you can just remove this table, convert the file successfully and then locate the SQL scripts and re-insert them into the project. I haven't looked at that for years.